# Strange Ajax/jQuery/PHP login issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamic login header. 2 links, login / register and profile / logout.

I have a php class function that was being used to check if logged in and displaying relevant links, it worked fine.

I then moved to an ajax login as I didn't want a page refresh and the login box drops down and rolls back up.  Again, it works fine.

I've noticed a slight issue, by slight I mean very irritating :)

Once logged in, Every single page refresh on new page shows a flicker where 'profile' becomes 'login' and then flickers back again.  It only happens when the page is loading and doesn't last long but it's not very nice.

Could someone help me solve it please?  I'm pretty new to Ajax/jQuery and spent ages wiht the help of some guys in here getting the ajax/jquery part functional in the first place.

this is script that toggles the login divs

```
<script>
        window.onload = function(){
            $(function() {
                var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($general->loggedIn()); ?>;
                $("#loggedIn").toggle(loggedIn);
                $("#loggedOut").toggle(!loggedIn);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks

EDIT: Ajax

```
function validLogin(){

$('#error').hide();
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

if(username == ""){
    $('input#username').focus();
    return false;
}

if(password == ""){
    $('input#password').focus();
    return false;
}

var params = {username: username, password: password};
var url = "../loginProcessAjax.php";

$("#statusLogin").show();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= '<img src="../images/loginLoading.gif" /> checking...' ;
    },

    success: function(data) {

        $("#statusLogin").hide();

        if(data.success == true){

            $('#loggedIn').show();
            $('#loginContent').slideToggle();
            $('#loggedOut').hide();

        }else{
           // alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
            $("#error").show().html(data.message);
        }

    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
 }
```

Comment: Maybe apply a `display: none;` CSS rule and then show it on `$(window).load()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// CSS-Stylesheet 
#loggedIn,
#loggedOut {display: none}

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($general->loggedIn()); ?>;     
            if (loggedIn == true) { // i can just guess here...
                $("#loggedIn").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#loggedOut").show();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: what type is var loggedIn ?
the ur variable is not **true**.

try:  if (loggedIn == "true")

Comment: //function to check if the user is logged in
public function loggedIn(){

 return (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
}//end function

Comment: They flash up and then disappear.-.-

Comment: set the style of #loggedIn and loggedOut to { display: none; } in your stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP to hide the unwanted element by doing the following

```
<?php
$loggedIn = $general->loggedIn();
?>
... Some HTML

<div>
    <div id="loggedIn" <?php echo ( $loggedIn ? '' : 'style="display: none;"' ); ?>>
        .... Logged in stuff
    </div>
    <div id="loggedOut" <?php echo ( !$loggedIn ? '' : 'style="display: none;"' ); ?>>
        .... Logged Out Stuff
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($loggedIn); ?>;

    $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
        ... Handle form submit
        ... When ajax returns true or false we can set loggedIn and then toggle the containers
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I can't do this because of the initial ajax call.  This was my first option but when you login for the first time, the page doesn't refresh so loggedIn is still false and still displays login until a refresh is made

Comment: This is essentailly exactly what I had before implementing the ajax.  Ajax kills the above on the initial login.

Comment: You can still have the ajax call there for when they log in and update the HTML after the ajax call, and you can still set the javascript variable using json_decode just as you are doing. Just get rid of the .toggle()'s in the window.onload and set the HTML in PHP

Comment: You could render both containers to the page, but use php to set the `display` property. The ajax call could switch the visible div on login.

Comment: Yep Jason P makes a valid point, have both HTML containers rendered and use PHP to set in inline style="display: none" on the one to hide by default.

Comment: The same way you are doing now. If you render both HTML elements to begin with you can just use $('#loggedIn').toggle()

Comment: @JasonP & Major - could you elaborate a bit more please? I've updated the Question with the ajax

Comment: Thankyou!  That looks elegant compared to what I'm doing.

Comment: Above where you mentioned ajax toggles - do you mean : if(data.success == true){

                $('#loginContent').slideToggle();

Comment: Your ajax request for the login form submission is fine. You no longer need the window.onload toggles.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions:

- If the [`script element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) is placed inside the [`body`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1), move
  it to [`head element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.1).
- Use the following script instead:

  ```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';
        var loggedIn = <?php echo json_encode($general->loggedIn()); ?>;
        $('#loggedIn').toggle(loggedIn);
        $('#loggedOut').toggle(!loggedIn);
    });
  ```
- Hide both links in the "logged in" `div` using `$('#loggedIn

  a).hide();` and then, show them on the `window.onload event` using
  `$('#loggedIn a).show();`. A bit dirty, bit it may work.

Comment: 'use strict' - what does that do?

Comment: script is in body but it's in the header include.  I'd rather it be in this one place that in the head of all the other pages

Comment: @SteveGreen In this case nothing really, but it's [good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1335881/2612112) to include it.